# What is the use of the position interface in the Linked list implementations?

Tags: java, list, linked-list, singly-linked-list

I do not see the use of the interface,
why can't we directly implement the getElement() method directly in the Node Class?

```
public interface Position <T> {
public T getElement();
}
```

Hereby the SNODE class:

```
public class SNode<T> implements Position<T> {

private T element;
private SNode<T> next;

public SNode(T e, SNode<T> n) {
    element = e;
    next = n;
}

public SNode<T> getNext() {
    return next;
}

public void setNext(SNode<T> next) {
    this.next = next;
}

public void setElement(T element) {
    this.element = element;
}

@Override
public T getElement() {
    return element;
}
}
```

Comment: And why need to do this?

Comment: If you only look at the declaration/definition of the class, then you will not see the *use* of the interface. In client code on the other hand, you may for instance pass an `SNode` to a method that takes a `Position` as argument. You would then see the "use" of the interface as the `SNode` is "used" as a `Position`.

Comment: Actually you can. In java you can have only 1 superclass, but you can implement all the interfaces you want. If your case ends with a *Node* class that could return the current element than is ok.

Comment: The answer to your question depends how this code is used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The position interface provides a general abstraction for the location of an element within a structure. A position acts as a marker/token within a broader list. A position *p*, which is associated with some element *e* in a list *L*, does not change, even if the index of *e* changes in *L* due to insertions or deletions elsewhere in the list. Nor does position *p* change if we replace the element *e* stored at *p* with another element. The only way in which a position becomes invalid is if that position is removed.

The reason for having it's definition of a position type allows position to serve as parameters to some methods and return values from other methods of a list.